# Expiration time for NTLM

Tags: ntlm, expiration

I am developing application that accesses SharePoint server(2013) with NTLM authentication via Rest API.

IF once authenticated, It doesn't need to add HTTP request header "authorization".

So I want to know authentication period or default expiration time(valid time) for NTLM authentication.

I searched for this, but couldn't find any information.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

NTLM is a connection oriented protocol. There is no concept of 'time out'. Every request is (re) authenticated by IIS (in this case).

Comment: As I tested, it worked well when deletes 'authorization' header from second request or generates authorization value from type3message every time I request. And got error when added 'authorization' header which is generated first every time I request. That's why I searched time out concept of NTLM. If there is no concept of 'time out', how can IIS manage session of NTLM?